# setState not causing a render React Native

Tags: javascript, http, react-native

I've been reading online that setState is asynchronous and that's why it doesn't cause a render when you mutate the state by using `setState()`, but I'm still not sure how to fix this issue.

Here is my sections for the sectionList:

```js
const sections = [
        { data: [{ value: this.state.balance, editable: true }], title: 'balance'},
      ];
```

I then do an API call and set this.state.balance, but the balance is not updated.

```js
dismiss() {
    fetch(API)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log(responseJson.balance);
      this.setState({
        balance: responseJson.balance
      });
      console.log("The balance is");
      console.log(this.state.balance);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

```js
render() {
    if (this.state.user) {
      const sections = [
        { data: [{ value: 0 }], title: 'Completed challenges'},
        { data: [{ value: this.state.balance, editable: true }], title: 'balance' },
      ];
      return (
        <SectionList
          style={styles.container}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          renderSectionHeader={this._renderSectionHeader}
          stickySectionHeadersEnabled={true}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
          ListHeaderComponent={() => this._ListHeader()}
          sections={sections}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Button title="Sign in" onPress={() => {this.goToLogin()}}></Button>
        </View>
      );
     }
  }
```

The logs correctly print the values.

Can someone help with this.

Comment: Can you show your render method?

Comment: sure, will add it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you re-define sections in render as constant. Use this.state directly.

```
render() {
  if (this.state.user) {
    return (
      <SectionList
        style={styles.container}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
        renderSectionHeader={this._renderSectionHeader}
        stickySectionHeadersEnabled={true}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        ListHeaderComponent={() => this._ListHeader()}
        sections={[
          { data: [{ value: 0 }], title: 'Completed challenges'},
          { data: [{ value: this.state.balance, editable: true }], title: 'balance' },
        ]}
      />
    );
  } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Button title="Sign in" onPress={() => {this.goToLogin()}}></Button>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```